# List of relevant RPC Protocols

Tags: json, soap, rpc, xml-rpc

I need to evaluate and dig more into the use of Remote Procedure Call Protocols (over the network) and haven't found a comprehensive list of which I could include.

There are some I already know from experience like

- RMI
- "RESTful style RPCs"
- XML-RPC
- SOAP
- JSON-RPC
- (CORBA ?)
- GWT-RPC and other Vendor specific ones, commonly used

But I'm still not sure if I am missing some important ones. I want to keep the evaluation as objective as possible so I just need some input on which I might have forgotten and maybe when and for what it is mainly used.

Comment: A lot of them are usage dependent, and language/platform sensitive. You've gotten most of the important ones.

Comment: That's true. I was aiming at the generic ones that have an approximate equal scope and can somehow be compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_(web_service_protocol))
- [Burlap](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/protocols/burlap.xtp)

Comment: ... and Burlap http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/protocols/burlap.xtp

Comment: Thinks I will take Hessian and Burlap into account, too.

Answer (score 1):

- DCE RPC
- Sun/ONC RPC
- OSI ROSE

Answer (score 1):

- [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- Websphere MQ
- [Spread](http://www.spread.org/)
- [PYRO](http://pyro.sourceforge.net/)

There are quite a few more but that should show you some of the diversity. Yes, CORBA is an RPC protocol from before the web. To find out more you should be able to Google on any of the RPC names people have given you, along with the word RPC.

Answer (score 0):

- [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf)
- [BERT-RPC](http://bert-rpc.org)

Answer (score 0):

[Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

- [Versile Platform](https://versile.com/platform/)

Answer (score 0):

- [Internet Communications Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Communications_Engine)